# How to change word-break characters in SQL Server Full-Text indexing

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, full-text-search

By default, when one tells SQL Server (currently using 2008) to Full-Text index a column, it treats characters such as "@" and "." as work-breakers, similarly to " ".

I'd like to restrict the work-breaking characters to just be " ", so that "joe.bloggs@somewhere.com" is treated as a single word.

It appears that one can choose a "Language for Word Breaker" against the indexed column - perhaps I need to set up a custom language?

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: Just found this:

http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-server-full-text-search-language-features/

Looks like one can install new languages... now all I need to do is create a new language ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to make your word breaker fly with SQL Server you have to disable signature verification and add your COM CLSID to the registry. For more info check out this post: http://blogs.msdn.com/shajan/default.aspx
It helped me a lot! However I never managed to create my own language so I simply hijacked an already existing one.

Answer (score 2):

According to [TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721269.aspx)'s article on SQL 2008 Full-Text Search:

> well-known published interfaces
>   provide the framework for Full-Text
>   Engine extensibility. For more
>   information, see the Microsoft
>   Developer Network (MSDN) topics
>   IFilter, [IWordBreaker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms691079(VS.85).aspx), and IStemmer.

So, at least according to this article, you can implement a custom IWordBreaker implementation (see http://www.siao2.com/2005/03/14/395199.aspx for more info) and get SQL to use it.

What I haven't found so far is how to plug your custom word-breaker into SQL itself-- how to tell SQL to use your word-breaker. Sorry for the incomplete answer... hope I got you at least part of the way to a solution.